# How to add FontAwesome Icons in Jade

Tags: pug, font-awesome

How can I add a FontAwesome icon to an `a` tag in Jade/Pug? I would also like to make it bold. Thanks in advance!
This is what I've tried:

```
a(href="#toTop", class="fa fa-arrow-up", aria-hidden="true")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do it this way

```
a(href='#')
  i.fa.fa-arrow-up(aria-hidden='true')
```

To add icons, you need to give the font-awesome classes to `i` tag and it should be inside of `a` tag.
Now you can apply the CSS and make it bold

Do not forget to add the font-awesome CDN.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you apply the CSS? When I put the icon in, my accompanying text seems to ignore my CSS file

Comment: just add one more class to `i` and add the CSS. Your text should be outside the `i` tag

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to reproduce your problem in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/gandreadis/pen/GyNMoL), but it works for me without problems. Have you maybe forgotten to add the FontAwesome CSS dependency to the header?

If that's were it went wrong, this would be the tag you'd need to add to the document header to make it work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```